# MySQL: unable to Insert CURRENT_TIMESTAMP using stored procedure - dynamic statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

When I call the below stored procedure, I get this error: 
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '01:53:26,1)' at line 1

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `update_xyz` (IN col_name VARCHAR(30), IN ip_add VARCHAR(24), IN lat FLOAT , IN longit FLOAT)
BEGIN
SET @col = col_name;
SET @a_ip = ip_add;
SET @lati = lat;
SET @longitu = longit;
IF ROW_COUNT()=0 THEN
SET @time1 = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
SET @sql_text2 = concat('INSERT INTO table1 (ip,latitude,longitude,date,',@col,') VALUES (',INET_ATON(@a_ip),',', @lati,',',  @longitu,',', @time1,',1)');
PREPARE stmt2 FROM @sql_text2;
EXECUTE stmt2;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;
END IF;
END
```

However if I remove @time1, the insertion proceeds leaving the DATETIME field as NULL.

Answer (score 1):

```
  change
  //SET @time1 = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();//remove this line

    SET @sql_text2 = concat('INSERT INTO table1 (ip,latitude,longitude,date,',@col,') VALUES (',INET_ATON(@a_ip),',', @lati,',',  @longitu,',', @time1,',1)');

replace this line.

   SET @sql_text2 = concat('INSERT INTO table1 (ip,latitude,longitude,date,',@col,') VALUES (',INET_ATON(@a_ip),',', @lati,',',  @longitu,',', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),',1)');
```

Answer (score 0):

when i debug your procedure and dynamic query then i get to know 
that your sessional variable is creating following query

```
    INSERT INTO table1 (ip,latitude,longitude,date,a)
 VALUES (3232235976,45.67,44.22,2017-02-21 12:30:00,1)
```

it means here date columns data should be in single quote like below 
'2017-02-21 00:00:00'

Then you will get rid your error

Have fun :-)

Comment: @TusharAgarwal your wc